# Finding all subspaces invariant under F.

Tags: representation-theory, invariant-theory, invariant-subspace

The question and its answer are given below:

[image]

[image]

But I do not know why is this the answer, could anyone explain this for me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the characteristic polynomial of a linear operator $\alpha$ on $\Bbb C^n$ has no multiple roots, then it has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, and since eigenvectors of distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent, we actually get a *basis* $v_1,\dots, v_n$ of eigenvectors, and coordinating in this basis, $\alpha$ becomes *diagonal*.
Now, coordinated in this basis, $e^{t\alpha}$ is still diagonal, so it has the same eigenvectors ($v_1,\dots, v_n$).

Comment: what do you mean by coordinating ?

Comment: Could you please state the names of the theorems you used (if any)? .....thank you

Comment: I mean to take the matrix of the transformation with respect to the eigenbasis. Then $\alpha(v_i)=\lambda_iv_i$ and $F(t)(v_i)=e^{t\lambda}v_i$.

Comment: I think you used a theorem called independent eigenvector theorem to say this  "eigenvectors of distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent" am I correct?

Comment: why coordinating in this basis $\alpha$ becomes diagonal Berci?

Comment: why if $e^{t \alpha}$ is still diagonal it will have the same eigenvectors?

Comment: You put the coordinates of $\alpha(v_i)$ into the $i$th column. This is $\lambda_iv_i$, coordinated as $(0,0,\dots, \lambda_i, 0,0,\dots)^T$. We get $\alpha^kv_i=\lambda_i^kv_i$ and hence $e^{t\alpha}v_i=\sum_k\frac{t\alpha^k}{k!}(v_i)=\sum\frac{t\lambda_i^k}{k!}v_i=e^{t\lambda_i}v_i$, so it's again an eigenvector.

Comment: why if you coordinate in this basis $\alpha$ become diagonal ..... it is a theorem?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3093798/finding-all-subspaces-invariant-under-f-2

Comment: I think in your last comment it should be $e^{t \alpha v_{i}}$...... the $v_{i}$ should be in the power of the exponential .....  am I correct?

Comment: No. Exponential is defined by its power series, that requires multiplication. It readily generalizes to linear transformations (multiplication being composition, the exponential resulting in a linear transformation on the same space), but we can't define $e^v$ for a general vector $v$..

Comment: And what is the relation between your answer and the answer given by the book in the question above?

Comment: I think that the t is raised to the kth power also

Comment: Yes, $t$ should be also raised to the $k$ in the power series. Well, still a Vandermonde determinant argument is required in that if $U$ is an invariant subspace for $e^{t\alpha}$, $u=\sum_j\alpha_j\in U$ with $\alpha_k\ne 0$, then $v_k\in U$..