# Finding all subspaces invariant under F.(2)

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, invariant-theory, invariant-subspace

I have a question regarding the question in the link here:

[Finding all subspaces invariant under F.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3088937/finding-all-subspaces-invariant-under-f)

The answer is so convincing in the above link but I just want to know why the matrix corresponding to the operator $\alpha$ will be diagonal, is there a theorem saying this?

**EDIT:**

Also I am wondering how is the answer mentioned in the above link by @Berci leads to the answer mentioned in the OP question in the above link (The answer at the back of the book)

Thanks!

Comment: The matrix of a linear transformation is diagonal w.r.t. basis $(v_i)$ iff each basis vector $v_i$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: is this a theorem@Berci?

Comment: Well, this easily follows from the definition of a matrix of a linear map w.r.t. some basis. Nevertheless, we can call it a theorem.

Comment: Can you tell me a book where I could find this theorem in please? @Berci

Comment: Thank you I found it @Berci